# How can I get the UAC/elevation prompt to remember my local username?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, uac, elevation

I want to be able to run as a non-admin domain account for normal work and be prompted for elevation when needed. This is fine when not in a domain as the elevation prompt remembers my user name and I just have to enter my password. In a domain environment, however, the elevation prompt does not remember the domain (the local machine) or the username from the local machine. How can I get the UAC/Elevation prompt to remember this information?

[image: UAC prompt requires input for user name and password.]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Finally found the answer:

Launch C:\Windows\System32\gpedit.msc using Run As Administrator (from the right click menu) and enable the following setting:

Navigate to "Local Computer Policy", "Computer Configuration" "Administrative Templates", "Windows Components", "Credential User Interface".

Set "Enumerate administrator accounts on elevation" to "Enabled".

Now the UAC prompt shows all the local administrator accounts.

The prompt remembers the last account you selected.

To use the same one, just type the password and press return.

[image: The UAC prompt only asks for a password now.]

Comment: Nice answer, I like that one, adding it to my list of little things to try out and remember.
Must look at whether this is available via domain group policy as well.
Only thing I don't like is that it only lists local accounts which are in the admin group, so if I want to use a domain admin account, or some domain\PCTechSupportUser account which I have added to local admins via a restricted groups policy these don't show up.
So -1 for using this in corporate environments, but +3 for small installs, home groups etc.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when the user you are selecting is Other.  I like to have the Other account remembered, added to the enumeration, always on top, and remembered for all subsequent UAC invokations as I have a second domain account that behaves as a local admin does instead.

Comment: The effect of enabling this on my machine was that it simply asks Yes/No to the changes, but does not offer the option of choosing a particular account. That's all I really wanted anyway.

Answer (score 3):

For those using a Home edition of Windows which lacks the policy editor, you can create the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\CredUI` and add a `EnumerateAdministrators` of type `DWORD` set to **1**.