# How can to manually change the default (suggested / favourite) users of the Windows UAC dialog?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, passwords, uac, elevation

Whenever I want elevated rights (via the Windows 7 User Access Control dialog), I need to input the [LaptopLocalName]\administrator. Because the user is in the domain, you cannot even just type administrator without a domain prefix.

Windows 7 does not seem to cache the suggested entries. Together with the password this amounts to a lot of typing.

Any chance to put a list of "favorite admin users" into the registry or policies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual answer (or at least an equivalent workaround) can be found here: [How can I get the UAC/elevation prompt to remember my local username?](https://superuser.com/questions/28773/how-can-i-get-the-uac-elevation-prompt-to-remember-my-local-username/29025#29025).

Answer (score 1):

I only have an indirect answer.

I don't know of any way to monkey with the UAC, but I do know of a way of caching text in an an easily accessible manner.

For these purpose I use a clipboard replacement utility that has the ability to remember not only past clipboard data, but also permanent list(s) in which one can stock text strings that are easily accessible via a hotkey.

Gizmo's article [Best Free Clipboard Replacement Utility](http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-clipboard-replacement-utility.htm) recommends quite a few such utilities.

Comment: Good workaround. Ditto (the first suggestion in the article) has been a huge help for me in loads of situations, including ones like this. Can't live without it.

Comment: The problem with the clipboard approach is that the UAC prompt blocks all interaction with other programs (at least it should), to protect it from scripting. That could make it a little difficult to select the right entry. Clipboard pasting generally seems to work though.